# How do apply the flip-flop operator to cat output?

Tags: perl

I'm parsing a crash log using perl and I want to extract the backtrace component. I obtain the log file using the following command:

```
$log = `adb shell 'ls -d ./tombstones/*' |grep tombstone_ | tr '\r' ' ' | tail -n1 | xargs adb shell cat`;
```

(I'm not familiar with perl, as you can see)

I would like to scan the resulting variable (log) for backtrace sections. These sections exist between the text: "backtrace", and the following empty line.

My question is, how do I apply the flip flop operator to the local variable as if it were a file input?

Comment: You do not need to `cat` the output. When using backticks (or `qx()`) in scalar context, multiple line output is concatenated by default. Conversely, when in list context, you get a list of lines. Which might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the flip-flop operator? How about a regular expression?

```
@backtrace_sections = $log =~ /(^backtrace.*?)\n\n/gm;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is an equivalent of the construct

```
while (<>) {
    if (m/backtrace/ .. m/^$/) {
        # processing
    }
}
```

I see two ways to do this off the top of my head:

1. Use the backtick operator in array context:

   ```
   my @lines = qx{$your_command};
   for (@lines) {
       if (m/backtrace/ .. m/^$/) {
           # process
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `open` to open the file:

   ```
   open my $fh, '-|', qq{$your_command} or die "Can't open command: $!";
   while (<$fh>) {
       if (m/backtrace/ .. m/^$/) {
           # process
       }
   }
   close $fh or die "close failed: $! $?";
   ```

   Doing it this way has the nice effect that you don't have to read the entire output into memory.